# What is the text in a tag when it has thymeleaf in mean?

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm new in Thymeleaf and facing some lines of code like:

```
<p th:text="${message}">Hi!</p>
```

Variable `message` is specified in the controller of the view here. The result of above line is the value of the `message` variable. So, what is the actual role of `Hi!` text above? I've tried to set `message` to another variable which doesn't exist and nothing happened but the white screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual role of `Hi!` text is to be able to display the static view of the page in the browser during *prototyping*. Because there is no such attribute like `th:text` in HTML, value `Hi!` is just a stub.

During the processing of the template this value will be substituted by the value resulting from the evaluation of `${message}`.
Also during the processing in the dynamic view (as well as in generated source) the value `Hi!` will be ignored.

This feature helps your designer and developer to work on the very same template file and reduce the effort required to transform a static prototype into a working template file. The ability to do this is a feature called **Natural Templating**.

Comment: @cuongngo you are welcome! Haven't any idea, I think some people just use voting for fun. As for me I found this clear and well-formated question absolutely normal for those who just started using Thymeleaf and I upvoted it.

Comment: Thank you again @dima. It makes me wonder If my question is a stupid question. Thanks!

Comment: @ali `${...}` is used for variable expressions while `#{...}` is used for message expressions. See details https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#standard-expression-syntax

Answer (score 2):

The text between the tags will be displayed when the message variable will be undefined. When everything is ok Thymeleaf substitute the thext between tags with the variable value.